# How to catch Google Map Event with listener in vue.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

How to catch Google Map Event with listener

I want to be able to use [bounds_changes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=en) event with listner. However, in Vue.js, I cannot get it working; even though the event happens, it is not able to catch the event.
So, I want to add custom event listner using `addListener`, but I do not know where to start.

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Below is my code :

```
const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
const mapOptions  = {
    center: {
        lat: 37.5005794,
        lng: 126.9837758
    },
    zoomControl : false,
    zoom: 10,
    disableDefaultUI: true
};

const map = google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds(),
        northEast = {
            'lat' : bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
            'lng' : bounds.getNorthEast().lng()
        },
        southWest = {
            'lat' : bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
            'lng' : bounds.getSouthWest().lng()
        };

    console.log(northEast)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a [global event bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) in scenario like this

```
const EventBus = new Vue();

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "bounds_changed", function() {
  //   ...
  EventBus.$emit("bounds_changed", {
    bounds,
    northEast,
    southWest
  });
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  created() {
    EventBus.$on("bounds_changed", ({ bounds, northEast, southWest }) => {
      // put your operation in vue here
    });
  }
});
```